# How to hide full namespace name on fields with codeDom

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm trying to generate some code with codeDom but can't find a way to remove the full namespace on fields and variables.

For example:

```
var field = new CodeMemberField
            {
                Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final,
                Name = webElement.Name,
                Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(StringBuilder))
            };
```

Will generate a field that look like this:

```
public System.Text.StringBuilder myField
```

When I just want it to look like:

```
public StringBuilder myField
```

Even if I also added the System.Text namespace as a CodeNamespaceImport before. I tried to look in CodeGeneratorOptions but couldn't find anything about it.

All examples I see never have full namespace either so I start wonder if I made something different. Here is a full example:

```
var targetUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
var globalNamespace = new CodeNamespace();
globalNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(typeof(StringBuilder).Namespace));

var targetNamespace = new CodeNamespace("MyNamespace");
var targetClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("ClassName")
{
   IsClass = true,
   TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public
};

var field = new CodeMemberField
            {
                Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final,
                Name = "myField",
                Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(StringBuilder))
            };
targetClass.Members.Add(field);

targetNamespace.Types.Add(targetClass);
targetUnit.Namespaces.Add(globalNamespace);
targetUnit.Namespaces.Add(targetNamespace);

CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
var options = new CodeGeneratorOptions { BracingStyle = "C" };
var outputPath = Path.Combine(_outputPath, filename);
using (var sourceWriter = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
{
    provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(
                targetUnit, sourceWriter, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var field = new CodeMemberField
        {
            Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final,
            Name = webElement.Name,
            Type = new CodeTypeReference("StringBuilder")
        };
```

This should give you the desired output. 
Note, however, that it is recommended to use fully qualified names instead.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A CodeTypeReference can be initialized with a Type object or a string. It is generally recommended to use a Type to do this, although it may not always be possible. If initializing an instance of this class with a string, it is strongly recommended to always use fully qualified types, such as "System.Console" instead of just "Console", because not all languages support importing namespaces. Array types can be specified by either passing in a type object for an array or using one of the constructors that accept rank as a parameter.

If you know and control the context you are generating code for, feel free to use the ctor that takes a string, though.

Comment: "because not all languages support importing namespaces" CodeDOM was build so that you can generate code in different languages from the same object model. But if you don't need this (which is quite often), I think you can ignore that recommendation.

Comment: This is the only way to achieve what you are asking.